# How can I pass variable data to package.json file scripts as parameters?

Tags: npm, environment-variables, package.json

We rename our assets directory on every single git push to handle browser caching issues. This mean that we store a random variable in a config.json file in our project.

I'm trying to move from gulp to npm as a build process, and therefore need to access this stored variable somehow from within the package.json file.

How would I go about such a task, and is it even possible?

```
"scripts": {
"build-offers": "uglifyjs src/pages/offers/*.js -mc > [HERE I NEED TO PREFIX THE OUTPUT FOLDER USING THE config.json FILE CONTENT] assets/offers.js",
"offers": "npm run build-offers"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can acces environment variables in your scripts, but i think, that it isn't possible to read such variables from an other file with pure `package` scripts. Here is a way, you could do it within your `package.json`.

```
"config": {
  "prefix": "prefix"
},
"scripts": {
  "build-offers": "uglifyjs src/pages/offers/*.js -mc > %npm_package_config_prefix% assets/offers.js",
  ...
}
```

> **NOTE**: The above version only works under windows.